Quantum Computing - via Qiskit - error 403
A year ago, I registered in the IBM Quantum Computing app, which provides access to quantum computers and to simulators. I got an API key, and was able to run some programs.
However, lately, I try to log in in my account and the system answers me with the same page, and I am not able to get another/the same API key. In fact, when I run the programs I run a year ago, using the API key that I then got, the program replies with:
qiskit_ibm_runtime.api.exceptions.RequestsApiError: '403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/users/loginWithToken. Your IBM Quantum account has been disabled. Learn more: https://ibm.biz/BdfaME., Error code: 3485.'

I tried to contact IBM, but they have not been replying...
Any idea?
By the way: I use python 3.11 and qiskit 0.43.0.
The program:
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
#from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from IPython.display import display
from qiskit.visualization import *

# Loading your IBM Quantum account(s)
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum") # the error occurs here!

...

```


Hi, have you tried to check the link in the error? The answer to your error's there :  "Your IBM Quantum account has been disabled. Learn more: https://ibm.biz/BdfaME , Error code: 3485 "

But, how may I disabled it, since IBM doesn't reply? Do you have experience with IBM Quantum Computing? I put a new support request to IBM...

Try logging in to IBMQ account on the webpage. If you are able to do this, copy the API token shown in the top right.
Then make use of the code mentioned in this answer,this is the updated code for the latest version of qiskit and will help you use IBMQ from your local device.
If the error still persists, read the complete error message, like in this answer, your reason might be there.

Thanks! Solved!

First got to this website and see if you can login here, this is the latest IBM Quantum website. Once you are able to login you will be able to get your API. Also if you were only using a free plan for accessing IBM Quantum computers then I would suggest you should make a new account. My friend also faced a similar issue and the easiest solution that was recommended to him was to create a new account.
Next, looking at your code, I think the error that you are seeing is because you have not imported qiskit_ibm_runtime. You need to do from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService and the follow the instructions in this link to setup your access to IBM Quantum. You might have to install qiskit_ibm_runtime version that is compatible with qiskit 0.43.0.
Lastly, I would suggest that you should update qiskit installed in your system to qiskit >= 1.0.0. This is because qiskit was updated to 1.0.0 version in February 2024, and this 1.0.0 version is not backward compatible (meaning many API and the way qiskit is packaged has been changed).
An important note: Because the version 1.0.0 is not backward compatible you cannot do pip install -U qiskit or you should not install qiskit 1.0.0 with any previous qiskit versions (<0.46). Follow the "For users" section in this link and you will find how to install and setup qiskit 1.0.0 with any older qiskit version.
